# Microsoft Application Insights do not show up in Azure console, Fiddler shows 200 response from dc.services.visualstudio.com

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-application-insights, azureportal, telemetry

I have set up Application insights for one of our apps,

```
    private TelemetryClient telemetry = new TelemetryClient(new Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.TelemetryConfiguration("xxx"));

    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        telemetry.TrackPageView(new PageViewTelemetry { Name = filterContext?.HttpContext?.Request?.RawUrl });
        ViewBag.CurrentUser = db.GetCurrentUser();
    }
```

On every page load, it should fire tracking event.

I can see with fiddler that requests are being fired at `dc.services.visualstudio.com` and that i get 200 responses

[image]

but nothing in the azure console

[image]

**What could be going on, how do I debug this further?**

Comment: You might want to decrypt HTTPS messages in Fiddler as well. Right now you're looking at establishing a TLS tunnel rather than messages themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you show tracks pageview. Pageviews are not shown in the overview page of the application insigths resource.

Instead, in the left side menu in section *Usage* there is a menu item *Events*, try that one. On that page on the bottom there is a button *View More Insights*, it will show the pageviews.

Alternatively, in the left side menu click *Logs* (in section *Monitoring*) and execute a query like this:

```
pageViews
| order by timestamp desc
```

Finally, you can use *Transaction Search* from the left side menu and select Pageviews like this:

[image]